# Pentaho CDE Line Chart Legend Click Mode

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, ccc

I have a line chart with legend on my dashboard. I want to show all line on execute. and when i click the legend, it only shows the line i clicked. (not as the default: it remove the line i click)
Can anyone help?

Comment: This functionality is available in pie-chart as a default one.
so if you don't have limitation then use pie-chart.
other wise you have to make custom modifications for other than pie chart.

Comment: Thank you so much! do you have any example for custom modifications?

Comment: Just google it. you will find many.